# Hide conditionally button with CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a page with code who look like this:

```
<form id="editform" class="left " method="post" action="edit-account.php" name="editform">
<ul>
<li id="row_first">
<label for="first">First name</label>
<input id="first" type="text" value="Mike" name="first">
</li>
<li id="row_last">
<label for="last">Last name</label>
<input id="last" type="text" value="" name="last">
</li>
</ul>
<label for="submit_button"> </label>
<input id="submit_button" class="button" type="submit" value="Modify user profile" name="submit_button">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
</form>
```

My goal is to hide the Submit button only IF the field "first" contain the default value "Mike".

In practice if I use this CSS:

```
#submit_button.button{ display: none; }
```

this hide well the button but in all case and not only if "Mike" is the default value for field "first".

Any chance to do that using CSS?

Please note I don't have access to HTML page.. I'm allowed only to modify the external CSS file who style the page I'm trying to change.

Alternatively, if you have a Javascript solution, I could normally use that because I have access to an external JS file planned for modify some form element.

Comment: With your current HTML structure, there's no possible way to do this with pure CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS is not functional, it is for styling therefore this is not possible in CSS. You need to use JS for this task.

**Update:**

This JS should work for you:

```
var element = document.getElementById("first");
var btn = document.getElementById("submit_button"); 

function checkIfMike() {
    if(element.value == "Mike") {
        btn.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        btn.style.display = "block";
    } 
}

checkIfMike();
element.addEventListener("keyup", checkIfMike);
```

Comment: I have the possibility to modify an external JS file who can have effect on the form. Have you a JS suggestion code please ?

Comment: Many thank!! Your solution work well :-) I was able also to add by myself `element.readOnly = true;` for disable the field "first" and avoid button to returning back if user change field value. All the best. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

While CSS does allow you to target sibling elements based upon their attribute values, this would only get you half-way to your solution. For instance, the following will hide your submit button:

```css
#first[value='Mike'] ~ #submit_button {
    display: none;
}
```

This will turn the display property to none for any `#submit_button` element in the same container as any `#first` element whose value is `Mike`. This works for initially hiding the button, as well as hiding it when the user types in the key name. But, lacking a not-equals operator, CSS doesn't help us restore visibility when the value is *not* the target name.

Our other options is to use JavaScript. We would create a function that would perform this evaluation, and show or hide the submit button based upon the value of the first name field:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    // Reference all of our key elements, and values
    var name = "Mike",
        form = document.getElementById("editform"),
        inpt = document.getElementById("first"),
        sbmt = document.getElementById("submit_button");

    // A function to toggle visibility based on field value
    function setVisibility() {
        sbmt.style.display = (inpt.value.trim() === name) ? "none" : "";
    }

    // Call this function whenever input occurs on the field
    form.addEventListener("input", setVisibility, false);

    // Fire it once upon load for initial evaluation
    setVisibility();

}());
```

This should get you where you're wanting to be with regards to hiding/showing the submit button based upon the user-provided data.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/j2MRQ/

Comment: Well, technically, if the input weren't inside a list item, he *could* do `input#first[value="Mike"] ~ #submit_button.button { display: none }` which would hide the submit button whenever the default value was "Mike" which I believe is what he wants (he does say *default*, not *current*). But alas, he's incapable of changing the HTML.

Comment: @animuson Correct. Sibling elements do enjoy an advantage here. Great point

Comment: @animuson The solution you make mention here was the one I thinking but I was unable to find the correct syntax. If this is not possible to apply due to the fact the element is inside list item, so it seem I'm stuck :-(

Comment: @animuson After some testing, it seems that that solution wouldn't work either. Once the submit is hidden, values other than "Mike" wouldn't result in it being visible again. And to my knowledge, there isn't a `!=` attribute selector.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: I know. It only works for the default state. It matches the `value="Mike"` which doesn't change dynamically.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson You rock my friend !! :-)) Your solution work like a charm. Many thanks to you.

Comment: I spoken too quickly.. In fact if we change the value, the button return visible. So in my case, I would like apply .readOnly=true; for field "first" IF the value is Mike. Like that the button will not return back because user will not be able to change default value. I tried to insert this code but without success. Could you please help me again ?

Comment: @dotcom22 So the field has a value by default when the page is loaded. If that value is "Mike", you want the field to be `readonly`. If the value is not "Mike", the user can insert a name. If the user inserts "Mike", does the field become `readonly`?

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson. Yes you right..and yes again if user insert Mike where field must be readonly.. Unfortunately I'm not a coder..just an integrator with very poor javascript/php knowledges :-(

Comment: I finally found by myself.. Is necessary to add `inpt.readOnly = (inpt.value.trim() === name) ? "true" : "";` right below `sbmt.style.display = (inpt.value.trim() === name) ? "none" : "";` . Thank

Comment: @dotcom22 Try instead `inpt.readOnly = ( input.value.trim() == name );` No need for the rest.

Comment: I tested your short code but this don't work because now the field is not "readonly". No problem the longer version work well..I don't mind for few characters more :-)